# In VB6, how can I fix the "can't find library" error?

Tags: dll, reference

I'm using MSoft (msc.dll) in my VB6 project. When I tried to edit and compile the same project on a different PC, I encountered an error saying "Can't find the project or library". How can I resolve this issue?

I'm trying to add recordset in my project.